# Appium Inspector: Webview Contexts Show Android Security and Update Bulletin, Fiddler Echo Service

Tags: appium, android-webview, appium-inspector

I am using Appium version 2.2.1 (installed using NPM) to run a local appium server. I'm connecting a physical Samsung Tab Android Tablet running android version 10.

Using Appium (Appium.WebDriver,v5.0.0-rc.2) in my test project, when I call `GetContexts`, I get:

- `NATIVE_APP`
- `WEBVIEW_chrome`
- `WEBVIEW_com.package.name`

When I use the Appium Inspector (app version: 2023.11.1) and I switch to the Hybrid App mode, I find a different list of contexts:

- `NATIVE_APP`
- Android Security and Update Bulletins | Android Open Source Project (`WEBVIEW_chrome`)
- Fiddler Echo Service (`WEBVIEW_chrome`)
- Android Security and Update Bulletins | Android Open Source Project (`WEBVIEW_com.package.name`)
- Fiddler Echo Service (`WEBVIEW_com.package.name`)

[image: screenshot of appium context list]

I've never seen these versions before, and they do not display the same sort of elements that I would expect. I don't actually have any version of Fiddler installed, either.

Anyone have any idea what could cause Appium Inspector to display these odd context types? I haven't changed any of the capabilities that I use to start the Appium Inspector session.

```
{
  "platformName": "android",
  "appium:autoGrantPermissions": true,
  "appium:autoAcceptAlerts": true,
  "appium:network": true,
  "appium:platform": "android",
  "appium:os_version": 10,
  "appium:automationName": "uiautomator2",
  "appium:chromedriverExecutable": "\\Resources\\chrome_119.0.6045_win64\\chromedriver.exe"
}
```